# SVN merge with revision number grabs too many files

Tags: svn

I am using SVN version 1.6 and am having a lot of issues merging using the command line.  I am trying to merge a single revision (let's call it revision #5) from one branch to another.

I am merging using the command line.  I am CD'ed in the branch I want to merge into, and am trying the following commands:

- svn merge -r4:5 FROMBRANCH .
- svn merge -r4:5 FROMBRANCH
- svn merge -c5 FROMBRANCH .
- svn merge -c5 FROMBRANCH

None of these commands seem to work properly.  Each time I issue a merge command and then do an "svn status" I get a very long list of files.  The list includes the files from revision #5, plus many other files that I do not want to merge.

(Note: I have been making sure that no files have been changed locally by using "svn status".  I also have been reverting the changes after each merge attempt by using "svn revert . -R")

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified with svn log -v -c 5 _repositorypath_ that the 'extra' files you're getting were not part of revision 5?

Comment: Yes.  When I run svn log, I do only see the files in that revision.

Answer (score 3):

The long list of files displayed by "svn status" is probably due to "**mergeinfo**" properties updates.

As explained [here](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2009/11/where-did-that-mergeinfo-come-from/)  when doing a merge to <target branch>, Subversion updates existing mergeinfo in all subtrees of <target branch> which have a mergeinfo property set.

This unexpected behavior has been adressed in Subversion 1.7

> (from **Subversion 1.7** changelog)
>
> Merges no longer record mergeinfo (describing the merge) on subtrees
>   (that have their own explicit mergeinfo), if the subtree was
>   unaffected by the merge. This should greatly reduce the number of
>   spurious svn:mergeinfo property changes for users who have large
>   numbers of subtrees with explicit mergeinfo.
>
> If a change being merged contains svn:mergeinfo modifications these
>   will still be applied, just like any other property modifications. So
>   if the change being merged was itself the result of another merge
>   performed with a 1.5 or 1.6 client, excessive subtree mergeinfo
>   changes are still possible. Best results will be achieved for new
>   branches created and maintained exclusively with 1.7 clients.

Comment: Is this not purely relating to mergeinfo properties changes though? Like @Joni I get a long list of 'M'odified files (which aren't Modified since their contents are identical to the base copies even including line endings) after svn merge to my branch, that most definitely haven't changed in the original revision on my trunk that is the source of my merge.